# ASP.NET Core 3.0 application to IIS under Default Web Site/MySite does not work properly

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

My ASP.NET Core project runs outside of Default Web Site properly but it does not run under default web site on IIS.

Actually when I right click on application folder where under "Default Web Site" and browse my site in Chrome, it shows me login screen and address like this: `https://testserver.abc.com/test_site` or `https://testserver.abc.com/test_site/account/login`

After I enter login information (the information is true I tried in local developing machine) and it can't redirect to the home/index or another link, because the link turns `https://testserver.abc.com/account/login`. It is removing application folder name from link. I could not solve this redirection problem.

So that gives 404 not found error after login page. But If I add the application folder name to link it is working properly unless you click another link.

My code parts:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        services.AddDbContext<LabStokContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddMvc().AddNToastNotifyNoty();

        //Not: Dependency hizmetleri ayrı bir sınıfta çağırılıyor
        services.ServisEkle();

        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80/", "https://localhost:443/"));
        });


        var tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
            });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
            )
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

            });


        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();            

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80", "https://localhost:443").AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseNToastNotify();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });

    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private readonly IKisiService _kisiService;

    private readonly IAuthService _authService;

    private readonly ITokenHelper _tokenHelper;


    public AccountController(IKisiService kisiService, IAuthService authService, ITokenHelper tokenHelper)
    {

        _kisiService = kisiService;
        _authService = authService;
        _tokenHelper = tokenHelper;

    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {

        Task<OrgPerson> userToLogin = _authService.CheckUserToLogin(userForLoginDto);

        if (userToLogin.Result == null)
            return BadRequest(userToLogin.Result);

        kisi user = _kisiService.KisiGetirEPostaIle(userToLogin.Result.KullaniciAdi);

        if(user==null)
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");


        var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(user); 

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = _tokenHelper.GetClaimsPrincipal(result.Token);

        HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(principal));

        if (result != null)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return BadRequest(user);

    }



}


//launchsettings.json

{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15798",
      "sslPort": 44300
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "LabStokTakip": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
    

    }
  }
}



//appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=******;Database=******;User Id=*****;Password=******;"
  },
  "TokenOptions": {
    "Audience": "https://localhost:5001/",
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:5001/",
    "AccessTokenExpiration": 10,
    "SecurityKey": "************************************************************"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

Comment: please check the IIS  log or browser network monitor tool doe it gives any error message or not.also compare both the application setting is the same. which authentication you are using on both applications?

Comment: Thanks Jalpa for your answer. I figured out the problem. In my "login.cshtml " I used <form action="/Account/Login" method="post" class="pt-2" > And I added "~" before / and the problem solved. <form action="~/Account/Login" method="post" class="pt-2" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In my "login.cshtml " I used

```
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post" class="pt-2" >
```

And I added "~" before "/" and the problem solved.

```
 <form action="~/Account/Login" method="post" class="pt-2" >
```

this applies to other menu items link as ".." instead "~".